# How to solve equation with exponents multiplied with a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

I don't know how to tackle equation with exponents multiplied with a polynomial in general.

For example:

$100 =2^x(1+x)$

Currently, I ignore the polynomial part since it grows much slower. I solve for $100=2^x$ and let algorithm to test out numbers around the range.

Comment: You can possibly solve it numerically only, but not exactly (algebraically). If you just want existence of a solution, then continuity and intermediate value theorem will help. Fir example, we can say there will be at least one solution in the interval $(0,5)$.

Comment: What you have done is the best and only thing to do.

Comment: @AnuragA I'm pretty certain that this is doable with the Lambert $W$ function. I would count that as an exact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw): Write you equation as 
$$100 = 2^x(1+x)=\frac{1}{2}2^{1+x}(1+x),$$
with $y=1+x$ you get
$$200 = y2^y=y e^{y\ln 2} = \frac{1}{\ln 2} (y \ln 2) e^{y \ln 2} .$$
Now substitute $z=y \ln 2$ and use the definition of $W$ to solve for $z$
$$200 \ln 2 = z e^z \quad \Rightarrow z = W(200\ln 2) \quad \Rightarrow 
y = \frac{W(200\ln 2)}{\ln2}$$
So finally

> $$x = \frac{W(200\ln 2)}{\ln2} -1 \approx 4.2512070962222326$$

As an alternative you can use a simple iteration scheme from the equation
$$x_{n+1} = \ln \left(\frac{100}{1+x_n}\right) / \ln 2 $$
With your starting value $x_0=\log_2(100) \approx 6.6439$ you get the next iterates $3.7094, 4.4083, 4.2086, 4.2630, \dots$

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, equation that mix transcendental functions and polynomials have no closed-form solutions and you need to resort to numerical methods for the resolution of equations (such as Newton's).

In this particular case, you can reduce to the form

$$ze^z=c,$$ which was studied by [Lambert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Lambert). He defined a special function, which precisely gives the solution of this equation.